# ConcurrentHashMap value iterator can it return null

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I'm trying to understand the iterator code to ConcurrentHashMap and based on looking at the code it seems that it's possible for the `ConcurrentHashMap#values()#iterator` to return a null value.

I believe this can happen because, even though you can't add a null value, a call to remove will first mark a value as null.

Is this true or does the iterator have a way of handling this?

Comment: i see nothing in the ConcurrentHashMap code which sets the value of an existing entry to null (jdk 6 & 7).  where do you see that?

Comment: [See here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#remove(java.lang.Object)).  It returns the old value, so if there wasn't anything there, it returns null.

Comment: The documentation says "Like Hashtable but unlike HashMap, this class does not allow null to be used as a key or value." And if the implementation is correct, this means that you should never get a null value out of it. But bugs exists though...

Comment: I thought the remove method first locks the segment, then finds the Entry, then marks the value as null, then copies the previous elements and links them to the element immediately after the removed element, and last modifies the head.  This is why (i thought) the get method checks for a null value and if it find it then it locks the segment and checks again.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at how `get()` is implemented, it seems that ConcuurrentHashMap is coded to allow for a situation where the entry value is `null` due to a class initialization race (which is then handled via a call to `Segment.readValueUnderLock()`.  it appears that the value iterator does *not* ever check a value entry for `null`, so it seems you have a valid question (i don't know if there is some other volatile operation which happens during iteration which would alter this possibility).

However, there is this javadoc note on the `Segment.readValueUnderLock()` method:

> Reads value field of an entry under lock. Called if value 
>   field ever appears to be null. This is possible only if a 
>   compiler happens to reorder a HashEntry initialization with
>   its table assignment, which is legal under memory model
>   **but is not known to ever occur.**

(last emphasis mine).

Probably would be a good question for Doug Lea.